# Genus from Riemann surfaces to algebraic curves on $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, logic, field-theory, model-theory, riemann-surfaces

The notion of genus is quite intuitive on compact Riemann surfaces, as it is a topological notion that can be visualized in this case.

On the other hand, when defining an algebraic curve in characteristic $p > 0$ (elliptic curve over $F_p$ for instance), we lose that intuition.

I've read that Model Theory can "transfer" some statements over $\mathbb{C}$ to statements over the algebraic closure of $F_p$ (with possible exceptions on finitely many $p$ and restrictions on the set of "transferable" statements) [Edit: See [https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~adrien.deloro/teaching-archive/Moskva-ACF.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eadrien.deloro/teaching-archive/Moskva-ACF.pdf) Theorem 3.9 "Cross-Characteristic Transfer and Ax’s Theorem" for reference]

Now here are my questions :

- Could we obtain the notion of "genus" on algebraic curves over $F_p$ from the fact that this genus exists and can be expressed algebraically on compact Riemann surfaces ?
- Can we use Model Theory to deduce results about curves on $F_p$ based on what we know on compact Riemann surfaces ? How far could we go (Riemann-Roch, structure of an Elliptic Curve group, etc.) ?

Comment: Genus *already* has multiple purely algebraic interpretations - look up arithmetic and geometric genuses.

Comment: I know it has. My question is more: if we knew nothing about algebraic curves except on C and found out the notion of genus is actually an algebraic tool using complex analysis, could we then say using model theory: "that also defines the genus for curves on F_p" ?

Comment: I think the most useful definition of $g$ (of a function field) is the minimal integer such that for every divisor $D$ of degree $\ge g+1$ there is a non-constant rational function such that $div(f)\ge D$, it remains to prove that such a $g$ is finite (Riemann Roch). For an elliptic curve $Frac(\overline{k}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-ax-b))$ in characteristic not $2$ with the group law we can shift $A+B$ to $P+(-P)$ then $div(\frac1{x-x(P)})\ge P+(-P)$ so $g\le 1$.

Comment: This isn't a model theoretic idea, but: are you familiar with the idea of transferring results by fibering over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$? Given a variety with integer coefficients hence a map $X \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$, the corresponding varieties over $\mathbb Q$ (which is closely related to $\mathbb C$-models) and $\mathbb F_p$ for all primes $p$ are fibers of the family. Since genus can be described cohomologically in several ways, you could potentially use upper-semicontinuity to transfer between characteristics.

Comment: @TabesBridges I'm not familiar enough with schemes to understand everything you say but that looks like another way to define genus generically for those varieties.
What I would find interesting with a model theoretic approach is that you wouldn't have to introduce an algebraic definition of genus (cohomologically for instance). You would just use the topological one on C.

Comment: I’m a bit confused by the first of your questions, in that once one knows the genus is “expressible algebraically”, we have an algebraic definition, and so we can interpret it over any field we like. In my mind, an “algebraically expressible” invariant would be precisely one which exists algebra-geometrically, so will be interpretable over arbitrary fields. Knowing that the genus (or any other algebraic invariant) respects base change does give results for finite field things which lift to characteristic zero, but since not all varieties do lift, I don’t think this is the generality you want.